# VB excel macro code to remove colum data in sheet and insert to other sheet and list empty column

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I am having issues with my code. I have an excel sheet **a** that has 7 columns. I want to copy and add first 5 columns of the selected/highlighted row and add them to sheet **b**'s very first empty row and deleting the remaining 2 columns all while pressing update button:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Range("F:G").Select
    Range("A:E").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Instock").Select
    Range("A280").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Cells.Select
    Range("A256").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Instock").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Instock").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "B2:B4096"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Instock").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "A2:A4096"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Instock").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:G4096")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Sheets("Checked Out").Select
    Rows("3:3").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("H17").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the sorting for?

Comment: its sorting column **a** of sheet "b" which are numbers after they have been inserted in sheet "b"

Comment: Oh ok. You didn't mention that above so got confused. What's the problem with your code?

Comment: its deleting row 3 column 3 info in sheet a, where as I want it to delete the SELECTED row that I have chosen and cut entire row, from sheet a and insert column a-e and deleting column f & g into sheet b

Comment: Well, you did `Rows("3:3").Select | Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp` so not sure what you expect XD Not sure what you mean by `chosen` row. You want to start by creating objects for your sheets and ranges. Look up `set`.

Comment: yes I know that I specifically chose row 3, I am new to excel macros and VB and I wanted to see if what I was trying to accomplish worked somewhat...I didn't know how to code it so that it deletes the selected row that I have highlighted and tested it with deleting row 3-(Rows("3:3").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp) ...

Comment: Ok. Well, you're going to have to study your code to understand what you need to do. Step through it line by line via F8. Edit: I will be here for about another hour so feel free to ask questions if you get stuck on a particular line.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather you have 2 worksheets

- Instock
- Checked Out

When you press update you want to:

- Add the first 5 column values of the selected row from [Checked Out] to [Instock]
- Clear the values in column 6 and 7 of the selected row from [Checked Out]
- Sort [Instock]

Try this:

```
Public Sub MoveStockItems()
    If Not (ActiveSheet.Name = "Checked Out") Then Exit Sub
    Dim newRow As Long, rw As Long

    rw = ActiveCell.Row
    With Sheets("Instock")
        newRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(newRow, 1) = Cells(rw, 1)
        .Cells(newRow, 2) = Cells(rw, 2)
        .Cells(newRow, 3) = Cells(rw, 3)
        .Cells(newRow, 4) = Cells(rw, 4)
        .Cells(newRow, 5) = Cells(rw, 5)
        Cells(rw, 6) = ""
        Cells(rw, 7) = ""
    End With
    Call SortInstock
End Sub

Public Sub SortInstock()
    Dim rowCount As Long
    With Worksheets("Instock")
         rowCount = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("B2:B" & rowCount), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("A2:A" & rowCount), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    End With

    With Worksheets("Instock").Sort
        .SetRange Worksheets("Instock").UsedRange
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Paste this code into a code module then assign a shortcut key to MoveStockItems.

**Usage:**Select a cell on [Checked Out] press the shortcut k to run the macro.